# HTML select onchange update query

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I have a form with two select dropdowns. One with countries and one with universities. The country dropdown is populated from a MySQL database showing all countries inputted. At first I want the university dropdown to be populated with all the universities in the system however the end user wants the system to be dynamic and learn as it goes on so at this moment in time the dropdown doesn't show any data.

```
<select name="academicdropdown" onchange="countrysortlist()" style="width:178px">
<option value"">Sort By Country</option>
<option value"All" style="font-weight:bold; font-style:italic">All Countries</option>
<?php

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($countryresult2)) {

    $id = $row["country_id"];
    $country = $row["country"];
    echo "<option value='$id'>$country</option>\n";
}
?>
</select>

<select name="universitydropdown" onclick="unilist()" style="width:154px">
<option value"">University</option>
<?php

    if(isset($_SESSION['appformuniversity'])) {

    if($_SESSION['appformacademic'] == "universitylist") {

        $universityinput = $_SESSION['appformuniversitylist'];
                                                    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($universityresult)) {
                                                        $universityid = $row["university_id"];
                                                                $university = $row["university_name"];
                                                        if($universityid == $universityinput) {
                                                            echo "<option value='$universityid' selected='selected'>$university</option>\n";
                                                        }
        else {
                                                        echo "<option value='$universityid'>$university</option>\n";
                                                        }
    }
    }
else {
                                                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($universityresult)) {

        $universityid = $row["university_id"];
        $university = $row["university_name"];
        echo "<option value='$universityid'>$university</option>\n";
                                                    }
}
}
else {

   while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($universityresult)) {

            $universityid = $row["university_id"];
    $university = $row["university_name"];
            echo "<option value='$universityid'>$university</option>\n";
   }
}
?>
</select></td></tr>
```

What I would like to do is when the user selects one of the countries in the country dropdown, it will update the universities dropdown with universities that are within that country. I know you have to use the onchange event but I do not know how to do the scripting side? Any help would be appreciated.

My university query at the moment is

```
$universitysql = "SELECT * FROM university ORDER BY university_name ASC" ;
```

Thanks in advance for any help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use AJAX for this. If you know jQuery it would be easier. Just include the jquery.js file. Then write the AJAX in the `onchange` function of the country dropdown. In the `onchange` method just pass the ID of the country. Then in your AJAX method send
ID to a PHP page. In that page generate the whole option list from the SQL query using that country ID. Make a relation between two tables i.e. every university row should contain country ID. Then echo the option list. In your AJAX method just change the university list dynamically using `innerHTML`. I am giving you example

1. `onchange` on country select

   ```
   onchange="countrysortlist(this.value)"
   ```
2. AJAX method in `countrysortlist` function

   ```
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'yourpage.php',  // change name
      data: "countryid="+id,  // country id
      success: function(data) {  // returns date
          $('.result').html(data); // result should be the class name of university dropdown
      }
   });
   ```

Comment: I have created everything as you have said. I've included the jquery file, I have then put the the ajax code in the countrysortlist function in another js file I am using and I have done my php page to get my results and print the results from the query. However when I select the country nothing changes? (I have put some sample universities in for now for testing) Do you know what could be wrong and does everything I have done sound correct? Thanks.

Comment: I have since got the country selection to do something however nothing appears in the university dropdown. On page load up all the universities appear but when I sort by country the uni dropdown goes blank and doesn't show the unis for that country. Any ideas why they are not showing? Another couple of questions are: do I use echo or print and also do I need to include the if statements that i showed in my code above or will these just appear anyway once the sort query is run? And also can I show all the universities on load up like I am already doing or is this affecting why it isn't running?

Comment: Do one thing.. just alert the data inside the success: function to see what values are coming from the php page...otherwise you have to change ur php code.

Comment: When I alert the data, all I get is [object Object]? My php file is as follows: connection details to the DB, gets the country id by doing $_POST["id"], checks that the id is either numeric all equals All, if it is 'All' does the query to get all universities again, then does a while loop and prints all the data by print "<option value='$universityid'> $university </option>\n";. This is the same for the else section but with a WHERE clause to unis by country id. Any ideas on what needs to change as to me the PHP is correct? How do I put all my others if statements in the print section on this?

Comment: Lets do one by one. First print the country id and the remaining code commented then print the sql query etc... and debug step by step.

Comment: I don't even think that the id is getting passed through to the php as I can't even echo or print it before any SQL queries are done?

Comment: I think u r messing up the things. The php file calling through the ajax should be different from the main page. You should send the country id through ajax later this will be useful to get all the universities under it.

Comment: The php page I have been using just does the sql queries and printing and that is it? I thought that is all I need?

Comment: This is my function for onchange event: function  countrysortlist(id) {

    $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'university-sort.php',  // query page
   data: id,  // country id
   success: function(data) {  // returns data
     alert( $('.universitydropdownclass').html(data)); // university dropdown
   }
  }); 
}. The university-sort file is just the file that does the queries from the country id. When i use the alert as show it only says object Object, even when I put echo "TEST"; in the php file. When remove the alert the dropdown just goes blank. Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try this extra parameter with your ajax method ...  dataType: 'text'

Comment: Here are the links to the two documents, I have just taken them from my code as there are 1k plus of lines. https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B91CoQ99PRlqZVBwNVFzNEJoR2s and the other is https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B91CoQ99PRlqbkstaDVrRDk0RkU. You can edit them within the link if you like and I can copy from there, so could comment it as well to let me know what you have done. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function countrysortlist()
{
   document.form_name.submit();
}
</script>
```

When you change the select option, the site will update submitting the form

```
<form name='form_name' action='' method='get'>
<select name="academicdropdown" onchange="countrysortlist()" style="width:178px">
...
</select>
</form>
```

Then the query will load just the universities within the country id submitted.

```
<?php
$country_id = $_GET['academicdropdown'];
$universitysql = "SELECT * FROM university where countryid = '$country_id' ORDER BY university_name ASC" ;
?>
```